# How to copy a windows 7 user profile when changing domains

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I need to connect my machine to a new domain soon. When I do so a new user profile will be created and I would like to copy all the settings/data from the old profile to the new one. This is a local profile only (no roaming). Running Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit.

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/50589/how-to-copy-user-profile-when-changing-domain) previous question on the same topic, it however only seems to address Windows XP and the solutions do not seem to apply to Win7.

Answer (score 11):

JayaprakashReddy answer led me in the right direction.

The solution is to (running as an admin) launch the [Windows Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Transfer-files-and-settings-from-another-computer) program. It is meant for migrating to a new computer, but you can choose to export only your profile.

Once you export it to a file on a local disk, launch it again, this time select "this is my new computer", click advanced and it will let you map from one profile to another and click transfer.

Worked like a charm (except no user specific registry data seems to have been copied).

Comment: Before I read this I just copied `\Users\<my_profile>` to `\Users\<domain_profile>`, being logged in as `my_profile` and it seems to have worked well too. All my browser panels I had opened got restored, passwords too, windows keyboard shortucts work as well. Haven't tried anything else though. Let's see...

Answer (score 4):

I used the free version of [User Profile Wizard](http://www.forensit.com/domain-migration.html). Seemed to work perfectly!

Comment: Thanks! I migrated a Windows 7 system from an old SBS 2003 domain to a Server 2012 domain without running the [Windows Easy Transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Easy_Transfer) program to copy profiles. After the system was in the new domain, Windows Easy Transfer could not see the profiles associated with accounts in the old domain. But I was able to still easily copy a profile on the system associated with the old domain to its counterpart in the new domain [using the User Profile Wizard](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/windows/utilities/system/User_Profile_Wizard/).

Answer (score 3):

This might be helpful, have a look at it

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560801(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 2):

User State Migration Tool (USMT) for Windows 7

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=e263796c-c7e4-44d6-96dd-32e821c88a25&displaylang=en#Instructions

Comment: +1 for USMT! It's the only way to go!

Answer (score 2):

Using "Windows Easy Transfer" on the same Windows 7 computer for transferring a domain profile to a local user profile works as far as documents files and settings go, but fails for say Outlook mail.